# cannot make navigation package in melodic

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

I have install from source navigation package from githubmelodşc-devel branch but when I tried to build it opengl is not found from cmake, I couldn't solve issue. I have opengl libs and also I can build another packages. I didn't see the issue anyon who faced before. Thah's why I just tried to install dependencies, opengl from debian packages but noone is able to solve my problem.
Here is the catkin_make o/p:

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps navigation
Base path: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws
Source space: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/src
Build space: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/build
Devel space: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/devel
Install space: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/install

Whitelisted packages: amcl, base_local_planner, carrot_planner, clear_costmap_recovery, costmap_2d, dwa_local_planner, fake_localization, global_planner, map_server, move_base, move_slow_and_clear, nav_core, navfn, navigation, rotate_recovery, voxel_grid
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Using CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES: amcl;base_local_planner;carrot_planner;clear_costmap_recovery;costmap_2d;dwa_local_planner;fake_localization;global_planner;map_server;move_base;move_slow_and_clear;nav_core;navfn;navigation;rotate_recovery;voxel_grid
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 16 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - navigation (metapackage)
-- ~~  - map_server
-- ~~  - amcl
-- ~~  - fake_localization
-- ~~  - voxel_grid
-- ~~  - costmap_2d
-- ~~  - nav_core
-- ~~  - base_local_planner
-- ~~  - carrot_planner
-- ~~  - clear_costmap_recovery
-- ~~  - dwa_local_planner
-- ~~  - move_slow_and_clear
-- ~~  - navfn
-- ~~  - global_planner
-- ~~  - rotate_recovery
-- ~~  - move_base
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/navigation)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'map_server'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/map_server)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'amcl'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/amcl)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'fake_localization'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/fake_localization)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'voxel_grid'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/voxel_grid)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'costmap_2d'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/costmap_2d)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- costmap_2d: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'nav_core'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/nav_core)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'base_local_planner'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/base_local_planner)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- base_local_planner: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'carrot_planner'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/carrot_planner)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'clear_costmap_recovery'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/clear_costmap_recovery)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'dwa_local_planner'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/dwa_local_planner)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'move_slow_and_clear'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/move_slow_and_clear)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'navfn'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/navfn)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- navfn: 0 messages, 2 services
-- NAVFN_HAVE_FLTK: 1, NETPBM: 1
-- FLTK found: adding navtest to build
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'global_planner'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/global_planner)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rotate_recovery'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/rotate_recovery)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'move_base'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/move_base)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "navtest" in directory /home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/src/navigation/navfn

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tugbakara/TOSSO/ws/robot_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:824: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

here is the libopengl:

```
dpkg -l |  grep opengl
ii  libopengl0:amd64                                            1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3                                               amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- OpenGL support
ii  libopengl0:i386                                             1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3                                               i386         Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- OpenGL support
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                                         5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6                                          amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64                                     5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6                                          amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL library development files
ii  python-opengl                                               3.1.0+dfsg-1                                                   all          Python bindings to OpenGL (Python 2)
ii  python-pyqt5.qtopengl
```

Comment: any suggestion?